# Default Tar Directory

Tags: directory, tar

I can't find the default directory .tar files are extracted to. OS - Ubuntu 16 4. Please don't answer : the same folder as the tar file, because it's not there (and every tutorial or question I've found uses that answer). Help, please ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the image is packed its directory structure can be preserved. To see the directory structure of a `tar` without un`tar`-ing it:

```
tar -ztvf my-data.tar.gz
```

The `-t` (short for `--list`):

> List  the  contents  of  an archive.  Arguments are optional.  When
>                 given, they specify the names of the members to list.

If it's not in the same directory as the `tar` file was extract then it will be in a subdirectory of that directory, unless `-C` or `--directory` was specified:

> ```
>    -C, --directory=DIR
>           Change  to  DIR  before  performing any operations.  This option is
>           order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.
> ```

Try `find . -name '*expected file*'` to search for it under the current directory.

Comment: Find helped, thank you. It wasn't in the directory or subdirectory I was in. It defaulted to another folder for some reason. Sent it to my home folder for some reason.

Comment: @eftexar what was the command you used to un-tar?

Comment: Either tar -xzf or -zxvf, was what I used.

Answer (score 1):

It's the directory that is encoded in the archive, unless changed with e.g. `-C` when extracting.  You can always get a listing of the file paths in the archive with

```
tar -t -f archive.tar
```

The paths stored in the archive are *almost always* relative paths (unless `-P` was used when creating the archive), which means that the contents of the archive will be unpacked as a file hierarchy in the current directory (unless changed with `-C`).

Comment: Most versions of tar that I've used over the ages will *always* remove the leading slash when adding an absolute path (`/path/to/foo`) so that when it is extracted it will always be relative to your current workign directory, unless as noted in another answer you use the `-C` option

Comment: @ivanivan With `-P`, the absolute pathnames are not stripped of their initial `/` when archiving. That's why I said "almost always".

Answer (score 0):

The `tar` command extracts files in its [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). When you run `tar` from a shell, that's the current working directory of the shell, the one that's set by the `cd` command, displayed by the `pwd` command, and sometimes displayed in the prompt. The extraction directory can be changed with the `-C` option.

Many tar files have all the files inside a single top-level directory (relative to the extraction directory), usually with a name that resembles the tar file. In this case all the extracted files are under that directory. But that's not an obligation, there are many tar files that contain multiple top-level directories and top-level files. On the other hand, `tar` on Ubuntu and on most other systems won't extract any files outside of the extraction directory.

The extraction directory does not depend on the location of the tar file at all. (That's for the `tar` command, and generally most command line archive manipulation programs. GUI programs might behave differently.) The extraction directory is the location of the tar file if the tar file name argument passed to `tar` doesn't contain any directory part, but in general it could be anywhere.

If you don't remember what the current directory was when you ran the `tar` command, check your shell history (in bash, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then type `tar`; press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> again to repeat the search). If you find a relative path to the archive (e.g. `tar xf subdir/archive.tar`), you may be able to work out what the current directory was (with this example, it was the parent of the directory containing the archive). Of course this won't always help, for example if the path is an absolute one.

If you can't find the files, you can try to look for files that were created or modified (more precisely, any change whatsoever made to the file or its properties) in the right time range, with the command [`find`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find) and its `-ctime` or `-cmin` option, e.g.

```
find ~ -cmin +30 -cmin -61
```

to look for files that were changed between 30 and 60 minutes ago under your home directory. Instead of `-cmin` and `-ctime` you may use `-cnewer somefile` to compare the change time with that of the file `somefile`. You can add `-name foo` at the end of the `find` command to narrow down to a specific file name contained in the archive (without any directory part).

If you ran `tar` the previous day or before then the [locate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)) database may let you know where your file is. For example, if the archive contains a file `some/directory/myfile.txt` then `locate some/directory/myfile.txt` will tell you where such a file can be found.